# Magento new custom block module

Tags: magento-1.8, module, php, blocks, xml

I'm using Magento version **1.8.1.0.**

I'm trying to create a new custom block module, which I'll use for creating a new home page.

- Namespace: Crusader
- Module: CLHomePage
- Block Type: crusade home
- Class: Qwerty (just for now while testing)
- Design Package: crusader
- Theme: default

This is what I have so far:

\app\etc\modules\Crusader_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Crusader_CLHomePage>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Crusader_CLHomePage>
    </modules>
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Crusader\CLHomePage\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config> 
    <modules>
        <Crusader_CLHomePage>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Crusader_CLHomePage>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <crusaderhome>
                <class>Crusader_CLHomePage_Block</class>
            </crusaderhome>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Crusader\CLHomePage\Block\Qwerty.php

```
<?php
class Crusader_CLHomePage_Block_Qwerty extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    // Methods (optional)
}
?>
```

\app\design\frontend\crusader\default\layout\local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="homepage" template="crusader/home.phtml">
                <block type="crusaderhome/qwerty" name="homeads" as="homeads" template="crusader/homeads.phtml" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

\app\design\frontend\crusader\default\template\crusader\home.phtml

```
<div id="home">
<p>Home Wrapper</p>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('homeads'); ?>
</div>
```

\app\design\frontend\crusader\default\template\crusader\homeads.phtml

```
<p>Adverts</p>
```

Now, with the above in place, my home page shows just "Home Wrapper", so the content of `home.phtml` is displayed, but not the content of `homeads.phtml`.

If I change the block type for `homeads` to `core/template`, it works, and I see both "Home Wrapper" and "Adverts". So I know the problem is something to do with the reference to my new block type (called crusade home).

What am I doing wrong here..?

**EDIT**

After suggestions in answers, I've updated some files as follows, but it still doesn't work:

\app\etc\modules\Crusader_Home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Crusader_Home>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Crusader_Home>
    </modules>
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Crusader\Home\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config> 
    <modules>
        <Crusader_Home>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Crusader_Home>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <crusader_home>
                <class>Crusader_Home_Block</class>
            </crusader_home>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Crusader\Home\Block\Qwerty.php

```
<?php
class Crusader_Home_Block_Qwerty extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    // Methods (optional)
}
?>
```

\app\design\frontend\crusader\default\layout\local.xml (simplified to only use one block instead of the nested blocks I was trying before)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="crusader_home/qwerty" name="homepage" template="crusader/home.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

\app\design\frontend\crusader\default\template\crusader\home.phtml

```
<p>Home</p>
```

So I'm still in a position where nothing shows.

After being prompted by @FabianBlechschmidt I've turned the logs on, and this shows in exception.log:

```
2014-04-09T14:04:54+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Crusader_Home_Block_Qwerty' in W:\stores\magento-dev\app\Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(27744): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(27686): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('crusader_home/q...', Array)
#2 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(27721): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('crusader_home/q...', 'homepage')
#3 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(27488): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('crusader_home/q...', 'homepage')
#4 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(27454): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(27459): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(13895): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(11274): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(11213): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 W:\stores\magento-dev\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(13969): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(18331): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(17865): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 W:\stores\magento-dev\includes\src\__default.php(20465): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 W:\stores\magento-dev\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 W:\stores\magento-dev\index.php(176): Mage::run('crusadergifts', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Any ideas what's happening..??

**EDIT No 2**

@Malachy Found the answer... It was the compiler. I disabled the compiler and it seems to work now.

Comment: I assume, you have a typo somewhere, check uppercase/lowercase of filenames. The files look fine. Did you clean the config cache?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I've checked my uppercase/lowercase in code and file names - looks ok to me. Everything above is pasted from my files. I have all cache turned off at the moment, and I've just cleared all cache and tried again - still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check system.log and exception.log? If there is nothing in it, I would start debugging in MAge_Core_Model_Config->getGroupedClassName(). Beside this: Please have a look in the [great debugging tutorial](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and report back.

Comment: I've not used the logs before. I've enabled them now, and exception.log is showing: `exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Crusader_Home_Block_Qwerty'`

Comment: I've updated the module name in line with the other answer here, hence the block type name (CLHomePage -> Home).

Comment: @CrusaderLtd, refer this http://www.magentolearning.com/creating-a-block-in-magento/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find the whole XML thing difficult so I am sympathetic to your cause here.

It looks to me like there is a discrepancy with your class name and your block XML

ie

```
class Crusader_CLHomePage_Block_Qwerty extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
```

and

```
    <block type="core/template" name="homepage" template="crusader/home.phtml">
        <block type="crusaderhome/qwerty" name="homeads" as="homeads" template="crusader/homeads.phtml" />
    </block>
```

Let's start with the block type and work backward. I think here I would expect to see something like

```
<block type="crusader_home/qwerty" ...
```

and that *type* would refer Magento to the class

```
Crusader_Home_Block_Qwerty extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
```

Continuing to work backward on this tack, the file app\code\local\Crusader\CLHomePage\etc\config.xml would need to be modified to ***something like***

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <crusader_home>
            <class>Crusader_Home_Block</class>
        </crusader_home>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

It points Magento to all classes starting 'Crusader_Home_Block_*'. And now I think you need to rename your module Crusader_Home instead of Crusader_CLHomePage and change the folder names accordingly...

***AND / BUT*** I strongly recommend you change your module name. Only ever use *one* capital letter at the start of the module name not three and don't put capital letters in the middle of the name either.

You may want to look into some of the tools available for generating modules. I find them very useful for avoiding typing errors. I use [this one by the very clever people at MGT Commerce](http://www.mgt-commerce.com/kickstarter/) (it has simplicity on its side) and [this one is all-encompassing and an astonishing piece of coding by Silk Software](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/).

***EDIT following comments below

Additionally based on the error log I think the problem is that Magento can't find your class file. So double-check the caches are refreshed or off, particularly XML cache, and that the **compiler is off or re-enabled**.

Comment: thanks, I've tried your suggestions. I've renamed my module to 'Home' and updated all the references and folders. Still doesn't work. I'll edit my question to show the changes.

Comment: It looks better certainly. I wonder if there is still a sneaky typing error somewhere. Based on the error log I think the problem is that Magento can't find your class file. So double check the caches are refreshed or off esp. XML cache and the the compiler is off or re-enabled. It wouldn't be a file permission issue would it?

Comment: You mentioned the magic word - Complier... I disabled the complier and it seems to work now. Thank you! If you add this as an answer I'll accept it for you! :-)

Comment: Actually, it was not *just* the compiler. Your original XML `<block type="crusaderhome/qwerty"` is incorrect. The solution is to both a) correct the XML *and* b) re-compile

Answer (score -1):

reply your question at the first place

```
    <block type="core/template" name="homepage" template="crusader/home.phtml">
       <block type="crusaderhome/qwerty" name="homeads" as="homeads" template="crusader/homeads.phtml" />
    </block>
```

should be replace by

```
<block type="core/template" name="homepage" template="crusader/home.phtml"></block>
<block type="crusaderhome/qwerty" name="homeads" as="homeads" 
template="crusader/homeads.phtml" />
```

because homeads is not the child of homepage. I think this would work.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that before with no luck. The parent/child thing was working fine when the block type was core/template (rather than my custom block type) so my problem is not block placement.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem and resolved it by replacing following code in config.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <crusaderhome>
            <class>Crusader_CLHomePage_Block</class>
        </crusaderhome>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

to this

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <crusader_clhomepage>
            <class>Crusader_CLHomePage_Block</class>
        </crusader_clhomepage>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

It should solve the problem.