# Custom module's block doesn't show up - xml layout file 'type' issue?

Tags: blocks, custom-block

Block created inside custom module doesn't show up in the fron-end.

Namespace: Fmat

Module: FtPrices

Custom Block file: Fmat/FtPrices/Block/Product/View/Tierprices.php

---

custom block php file:

```
<?php
 class Fmat_FtPrices_Block_Product_View_Tierprices extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
 }
?>
```

block's definition in module's config.xml (...etc/config.xml)

```
<global>
(...)
    <blocks>
        <fmat_ftprices>
            <class>Fmat_FtPrices_Block_Product_View_Tierprices</class>
        </fmat_ftprices>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

in module's layout file:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="fmat_ftprices/product_view_tierprices" name="product.custom.tierprices" as="custom_tierprices" template="fmat/ftprices/product/view/tierprices.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

in `catalog/product/view.phtml` I get the block via:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_tierprices');
```

Once I change block type in module's layout file from `type="fmat_ftprices/product_view_tierprices"` to `type="catalog/product_view"` the template shows up in the front end. Can you see any errors in my files?

I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: can you please put config.xml .. All above code seems ok. Also please  check module Fmat_FtPrices.xml exits or not at app/etc/modules/

Comment: Can you please show full code of config xml

Comment: @AmitBera I'm not on my development machine now. I'll update my question once I get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it didn't work for me was in module's config.xml:

```
<global>
 (...)
  <blocks>
   <fmat_ftprices>
    <class>Fmat_FtPrices_Block</class>
   </fmat_ftprices>
  </blocks>
</global>
```

I've removed `_Product_View_Tierprices` from block's class definition(leaving this fragment in the actual class name) and it worked.

I think that the naming here is confusing. On the one hand you're defining something inside the `<class>` tag, but on the other you're supposed to write a 'path' to Block classes, not the actual class name.

---

If someone still experiences this problem there is an interesting thread with similar issue but different solution(compiler): 
[Magento new custom block module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18098/magento-new-custom-block-module)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I struggle to get any module to work when the module name has CamelCase in it. FtPrices probably resolves to ft/prices at some point. Therefore my suggestion is to go through your module files and replace FtPrices with Ftprices. After that the filenames/paths with 'FtPrices' will need to be 'Ftprices'.

By tidying up the CamelCase ambiguities I think your module will work as you want - seems you know your stuff and know what to post for a meaningful question.

Comment: Thanks Woolfie, I've experienced some camelCasing naming issues before but I'm working on a shop that's not entirely under my control so I was hoping that it can be solved without renaming the module. Nevertheless I'll give it a try and leave some feedback soon :).

Comment: Unfortunately renaming the module didn't help. I'll need to do some more research. Thanks.